# Why show this error message "Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to integrate tesseract into my application. When I runs My application it's showing the bellow. If I remove tesseract file, the application is fine without errors. What might be the problem?

Error displayed is:

> ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Lutful Kabir/Project/Business Card Reader/DBZiCardReader/DBZiCardReader/build_dependencies/dependencies/lib/libtesseract_all.a(svpaint.o) and /Users/foyzulkarim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DBZiCardReader-awawphfeoprlwqgcmoohhievukcx/Build/Intermediates/DBZiCardReader.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DBZiCardReader.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o for architecture i386
>       Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1

How can i remove this error message?

Comment: Check your app-delegate imports for recursion and conflicts. The idea is that `main.m` usually has imported only delegate and UIKit headers, so the problem must be there.

Comment: Did you have any luck fixing this as I'm stuck with it too?

Answer (score 0):

clang has found 2 _main symbols.

- one in svpaint.o inside of libtesseract_all.a
- one in your main.m file

libtesseract is either expects you to have a project that relies on their main in svpaint.o (and perhaps there are some instructions to this effect), or that it expects you not to import anything that will cause svpaint.o to have to be included as a part of the link (perhaps you are importing a libtesseract header like svpaint.h … or importing something which imports it … and which is meant only as one of their examples for using their library …)